# Re-assign the task with designer workflow 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have to re-assign the task on the following conditions-

1. Reviewer rejects the document.
2. Approver rejects the document.
3. Final Reviewer / Publisher rejects the document.

On all the above conditions, I have to re-assign the task to **Editor Group**.
With **updated item** as a new subject in designer workflow 2013.

Comment: elaborate more regarding the problem, are you using out of the box approval WF or custom.

Comment: Out of the box designer workflow.

Comment: how do i hide a comment column and then show it as soon as the rejected button is clicked in sharepoint

Comment: Hi and welcome to SharePoint.StackExchange . You have posted a new question in the answer field, and I would advise you to ask a new question instead. Use the "Ask Question" button in the upper right corner. You can always find out more in the [Help Section](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to Do some workaround here.
create Custom column in list/Library, keep that column hidden.
assume that Reviewer has approved your Item.
Then Approver  rejects your item then add  text "Rejected" inside Custom column.
send Email to  Editor Group, that your request has been rejected.
trigger the event on item Update.
Once Item has been updated it will trigger workflow. then again New task is assign to Reviewer.
To change the Email body You can add conditions by using Custom Column values.

Comment: This could be sounds good answer!!

Comment: Keep me posted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a designer workflow and select **Assign Task** action.Along with that you have to configure the options users have to select i.e. Accepted, Rejected or Canceled. You have the automated conditions generated for each option where you can specify the task you wish to perform.

If above statement doesn't make sense to you then Just start with 2013 Designer workflow and you will know what I am saying. Its straight forward and easy.

Comment: Yeah, I have used designer 2013 workflow.
But If I have rejected the workflow then also I have to re-assign the task to appropriate group.
This workflow will finished once the **publisher** publish the document.
If any of the above group member had rejected then it will be re-assign task.

Answer (score 0):

You can here use State Machine Workflow. Like on all the conditions that you have mentioned if the authorized person has rejected it will again go to the editor group and in case if they have accepted, then you can set different conditions. 
For reference take a look on nintex workflow state machine approval , although i know this ques is not on Nintex, but it will be of great help to you as you can easily understand the concept of state machine workflow

Comment: I have to do this task with sequential workflow with out of the box (with Designer 2013)